# How to create array of viewports in MSDN DirectX applications?

Tags: c++, directx, viewport

As mentioned in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476480(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation, I need to provide two viewports to a same ID3D11DeviceContext however I could not find any documentation regarding how to create an array of viewports.

I can see in the documentation that we can provide an int number of viewports in the

```
void RSSetViewports(
  [in]                 UINT           NumViewports,
  [in, optional] const D3D11_VIEWPORT *pViewports
);
```

command and provide an array to the D3D11_VIEWPORT devices however I could not find any documentation on how to create an array of two viewports.

**EDIT**

I could find an example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205126(v=vs.85).aspx) which demonstrates how to use an array of viewports.
How it is mentioned there that

> You can create an array of viewports, but only one can be applied to a primitive output from the geometry shader. Only one viewport can be set active at a time

So how do I make sure both my viewports are being displayed all the time?

Comment: @NicoSchertler Can you help me out with a sample code on this. Sorry I am fairly new to directx programming and still getting a hang of different structures and syntax.

Comment: Please clarify why you need two viewports first. You should set the system variable `SV_ViewportArrayIndex` in the geometry shader to define which viewport to render on.